# D3 Circular Heat Chart increase segment height on mouseover

Tags: d3.js, charts

I created a circular heat chart of acoustic data, each layer of a circle is the same day and there are 24 parts of the circle representing the 24 hours in a day. I want to implement something so I could increase the segment height of all segments of the same date as the segment that is being moused over, while decreasing the height of all other segments accordingly in order to keep the arc radius the same.  Currently I am only able to select all segments from the same date, but I am having trouble figuring out how to manipulate the heights. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Here is an image where you mouseover a segment right now:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
    var radial_labels = ['2016-10-22', '2016-10-23', '2016-10-24', '2016-10-25', '2016-10-26', '2016-10-27', '2016-10-28', '2016-10-29', '2016-10-30'];

    var segment_labels = ['0:00', '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00', '5:00', '6:00', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00', '10:00', '11:00','12:00','13:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00','19:00','20:00','21:00','22:00','23:00'];

    loadCircularHeatMap(data,"#chart",radial_labels, segment_labels);


    function loadCircularHeatMap (dataset, dom_element_to_append_to,radial_labels,segment_labels) {

    var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};
    var width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right;

    var height = width;
    var innerRadius = 100;// width/14;

    var segmentHeight = (width - margin.top - margin.bottom - 2*innerRadius )/(2*radial_labels.length);

    var chart = circularHeatChart()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .segmentHeight(segmentHeight)
    .domain([0,0.5,1])
    .range(["#ffffd9", "#7fcdbb" ,"#225ea8"])
    .radialLabels(radial_labels)
    .segmentLabels(segment_labels);

    chart.accessor(function(d) {return d.Average;})

    var svg = d3.select(dom_element_to_append_to)
    .selectAll('svg')
    .data([dataset])
    .enter()
    .append('svg')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + ( (width )/2 - (radial_labels.length*segmentHeight + innerRadius)  ) + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(chart);




    var tooltip = d3.select(dom_element_to_append_to)
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'tooltip');

    tooltip.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'time');
    tooltip.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'average');
    tooltip.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'day');

    svg.selectAll("path")
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        console.log(d.Day);
        // increase the segment height of the one being hovered as well as all others of the same date
        // while decreasing the height of all others accordingly

        d3.selectAll("path.segment-"+d.Day).style("opacity", function (p) {return 0.6});

        tooltip.select('.time').html("<b> Time: " + d.Time + "</b>");
        tooltip.select('.day').html("<b> Date: " + d.Day + "</b>");
        tooltip.select('.average').html("<b> Value: " + d.Average + "</b>");
        tooltip.style('display', 'block');
        tooltip.style('opacity',2);
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(d) {
        tooltip.style('top', (d3.event.layerY + 10) + 'px')
        .style('left', (d3.event.layerX - 25) + 'px');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d) {
        tooltip.style('display', 'none');
        tooltip.style('opacity',0);
       //  var time = d.Time;
       //  var timeCleaned = time.split(":").join("-");
       //  var segment = d3.select("#segment-"+d.Day +"-"+timeCleaned); //designate selector variable for brevity
       //  var fillcolor = segment.select("desc").text();  //access original color from desc
       //  segment.style("fill", fillcolor);

        d3.selectAll("path.segment-"+d.Day).style("opacity", function (p) {return 1});
    })
    .append("desc") //append the current color as a desc element
    .text(function(d){ 
            var color = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,0.5,1]).range(["#ffffd9", "#7fcdbb" ,"#225ea8"]);
            // how to access a function within reusable charts
            console.log(color(d.Average));
            return color(d.Average);
        });
    }

function circularHeatChart() {
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 20},
    innerRadius = 20,
    numSegments = 24,
    segmentHeight = 20,
    domain = null,
    range = ["white", "red"],
    accessor = function(d) {return d;},
    radialLabels = segmentLabels = [];

    function chart(selection) {
        selection.each(function(data) {
            var svg = d3.select(this);

            var offset = innerRadius + Math.ceil(data.length / numSegments) * segmentHeight;
            g = svg.append("g")
                .classed("circular-heat", true)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + parseInt(margin.left + offset) + "," + parseInt(margin.top + offset) + ")");

            var autoDomain = false;
            if (domain === null) {
                domain = d3.extent(data, accessor);
                autoDomain = true;
            }
            var color = d3.scale.linear().domain(domain).range(range);
            if(autoDomain)
                domain = null;

            g.selectAll("path").data(data)
                .enter().append("path")
                // .attr("class","segment")
                .attr("class",function(d){return "segment-"+d.Day})
                .attr("id",function(d){
                     var time = d.Time;
                     var timeCleaned = time.split(":").join("-");
                     return "segment-"+d.Day +"-"+timeCleaned;})
                .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(ir).outerRadius(or).startAngle(sa).endAngle(ea))
                .attr("stroke", function(d) {return '#252525';})
                .attr("fill", function(d) {return color(accessor(d));});

            // Unique id so that the text path defs are unique - is there a better way to do this?
            var id = d3.selectAll(".circular-heat")[0].length;


            //Segment labels
            var segmentLabelOffset = 5;
            var r = innerRadius + Math.ceil(data.length / numSegments) * segmentHeight + segmentLabelOffset;
            labels = svg.append("g")
                .classed("labels", true)
                .classed("segment", true)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + parseInt(margin.left + offset) + "," + parseInt(margin.top + offset) + ")");

            labels.append("def")
                .append("path")
                .attr("id", "segment-label-path-"+id)
                .attr("d", "m0 -" + r + " a" + r + " " + r + " 0 1 1 -1 0");

            labels.selectAll("text")
                .data(segmentLabels).enter()
                .append("text")
                .append("textPath")
                .attr("xlink:href", "#segment-label-path-"+id)
                .style("font-size", "12px")
                .attr("startOffset", function(d, i) {return i * 100 / numSegments + 1.5+ "%";})
                .text(function(d) {return d;});
        });

    }

    /* Arc functions */
    ir = function(d, i) {
        return innerRadius + Math.floor(i/numSegments) * segmentHeight;
    }
    or = function(d, i) {
        return innerRadius + segmentHeight + Math.floor(i/numSegments) * segmentHeight;
    }
    sa = function(d, i) {
        return (i * 2 * Math.PI) / numSegments;
    }
    ea = function(d, i) {
        return ((i + 1) * 2 * Math.PI) / numSegments;
    }

    /* Configuration getters/setters */
    chart.margin = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return margin;
        margin = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.innerRadius = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return innerRadius;
        innerRadius = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.numSegments = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return numSegments;
        numSegments = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.segmentHeight = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return segmentHeight;
        segmentHeight = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.domain = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return domain;
        domain = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.range = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return range;
        range = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.radialLabels = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return radialLabels;
        if (_ == null) _ = [];
        radialLabels = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.segmentLabels = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return segmentLabels;
        if (_ == null) _ = [];
        segmentLabels = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.accessor = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return accessor;
        accessor = _;
        return chart;
    };

    return chart;
}
```

And here is a demo of what it is currently like:
http://jhjanicki.github.io/circular_heat_acoustic

Comment: I made a fiddle with your code and the data array, it makes helping you easier: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/fw9k5gLf/

Comment: Increase the segment height with transition or not?

Comment: That would be ideal, but even figuring out how to do it without transition first is good

Comment: @blackmiaool are you familiar with reusable chart updates? if so if you have time can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192283/d3-reusable-circular-heat-chart-cannot-successfully-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[My demo](https://jsfiddle.net/blackmiaool/7dq4a040/1/)

The core code snippet is as below:

```
var targetIndex=Math.floor(i/numSegments);//the layer you are hovering
var zoomSize=10;//inner 10px and outer 10px
var layerCnt=data.length/numSegments;


d3.selectAll("path.segment")//.arc indicates segment
    .transition().duration(200)//transtion effect
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()//set d again
        .innerRadius(ir)
        .outerRadius(or)
        .startAngle(sa)
        .endAngle(ea))


function getRadius(floor) {
    if(floor===0){//inner radius doesn't change
        return innerRadius;
    }
    if(floor===layerCnt){//outer radius doesn't change
        return innerRadius+layerCnt*segmentHeight;
    } 
    if(floor<=targetIndex){//it's math
        return innerRadius + floor * segmentHeight - zoomSize *(floor/targetIndex);    
    }else{//math again
        return innerRadius + floor * segmentHeight + zoomSize*((layerCnt-floor)/(layerCnt-targetIndex));  
    }                    
}

function ir(d, i) {                    
    return getRadius(Math.floor(i / numSegments));
}

function or(d, i) {
    return getRadius(Math.floor(i / numSegments) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I'm reading over the code again, could you explain why it's necessary to put it in a draw function and use setTimeout?

Comment: @jhjanicki I left my draft there...  I updated my answer to minimize the change.

Comment: thank you. could you explain the getRadius function a bit?

Comment: @jhjanicki It's pure math, hard to explain :(

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a path, you cannot increase it's height. But you can scale the path.

My algorithm is

- Get the centroid of the segment on mouse over.
- Scale the path on mouse over to 1.5 w.r.t centroid of the path.
- Move the selected path to top
- Scale back the path on mouse out to 1

Snippet to get the centroid:

```
function getBoundingBoxCenter (selection) {
  // get the DOM element from a D3 selection
  // you could also use "this" inside .each()
  var element = selection.node();
  // use the native SVG interface to get the bounding box
  var bbox = element.getBBox();
  // return the center of the bounding box
  return [bbox.x + bbox.width/2, bbox.y + bbox.height/2];
}
```

Snippet to move the selected element on top

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
  return this.each(function(){
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
};
```

On mouse over you do:

```
        var sel = d3.select(this);
    sel.moveToFront()

        var centroid = getBoundingBoxCenter(d3.select(this));
        //zoom in to the centroid
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(p) {
                return "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + centroid[1] + ")"
                        + "scale(" + 1.5 + ")"
                        + "translate(" + -centroid[0] + "," + -centroid[1] + ")";
  });
```

On mouse out do:

```
        var centroid = getBoundingBoxCenter(d3.select(this));
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(p) {
                return "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + centroid[1] + ")"
                        + "scale(" + 1 + ")"
                        + "translate(" + -centroid[0] + "," + -centroid[1] + ")";
  });
```

Special thanks to @Gerardo for putting this up on a fiddle :)

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n4brnphb/)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I understand better now how paths work. Is it pretty straightforward to extend your code so instead of just one segment all segments in the same layer is scaled up and the rest of the layers (those that are not of the same date as the one hovered) are scaled down?

Comment: ohh the problem with scaling the full row would be that segments will overlap over one another...it will not look good but yeah you can give it a try.

Comment: Ok, I might give it a shot anyway. So from what I understand, maybe what I'm trying to accomplish is difficult with paths?

Comment: No you can scale a path to increase the patch size...it is not diffcult

Comment: if you want to zoom all the paths then it will look clumsy like this https://jsfiddle.net/m7gqvjxk/1/

Comment: Hello, would you know the answer to this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696831/d3-force-directed-graph-why-dont-the-flags-appear